# How do I change my login method from GitHub to Stack Overflow for stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, login

I created my Stack Overflow account via GitHub, so every time I log in via GitHub. Folks at work recently blocked GitHub, and now I'm locked out of Stack Overflow at work too.

Comment: You can manage your logins [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current).

Comment: _Folks at work recently blocked Github_ Are you a programmer? Might be time to look for something new...

Comment: Lol yes @Clive IKR

Comment: @TheThonnu The answer to that question is pretty outdated.

Comment: That is an appalling company ethos to block an open source site that whole a whole lot of BSD or other licenses or unlicensed code that means you are allowed to use it for commercial use cases. fair enough if it was a GNU-only hosting platform but it's not, absolutely ludicrous, to try to leave the company ASA{ because clearly there is an imbecile who does not know how code licensing works but is enforcing changes they don't understand and if they are getting away with it whats next they block SO, SourceForge, Bit Bucket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AI Generated (meta the meta!):

To manage your logins for your Stack Overflow account, follow these steps:

1. Go to the Stack Overflow website and log in to your account.
2. Click on your profile picture in the top right corner of the page and select "Settings" from the drop-down menu.
3. On the settings page, select the "Account" tab.
4. Under the "Account" tab, you will see a section called "Logins" where you can manage the logins associated with your Stack Overflow account.
5. To add a new login, click on the "Add Login Method" button and follow the on-screen instructions to link a new account, such as your Google or Facebook account.
6. To remove a login, click on the "Remove" button next to the login you want to remove. Please note that if you remove your only login method, you will not be able to log in to your Stack Overflow account.

If you have any trouble with these steps, you can contact the Stack Overflow support team for assistance.

---

[Non-AI generated]
But this looks to be out of date. Instead,

- Once you're in Settings, under "Access", click "Your Logins"
- Then click "Add More Logins"

Comment: Maybe this AI can be used as the new frontend for Stack Overflow instead of the severely broken search engine results (a typical result is a low-scored question from 2015 with one or two low-quality answers. And it doesn't have ***any*** indication of where the canonical question is).

Comment: @PeterMortensen how to search stack overflow: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+query+here